# How to access images from internal recources in full screen image view pager activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to create my own activity for that im using reference of :

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

so in this code he have explained only how to get files from SD card.
Instead i want to access them from either android assets or drawable resources.

following is the code of function which returning images filepath from sd card.

From Util.java

```
// Reading file paths from SDCard
    public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths() {
        ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

        File directory = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);

        // check for directory
        if (directory.isDirectory()) {
            // getting list of file paths
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

            // Check for count
            if (listFiles.length > 0) {

                // loop through all files
                for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

                    // get file path
                    String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

                    // check for supported file extension
                    if (IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {
                        // Add image path to array list
                        filePaths.add(filePath);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // image directory is empty
                Toast.makeText(
                        _context,
                        AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                                + " is empty. Please load some images in it !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
            alert.setTitle("Error!");
            alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM
                    + " directory path is not valid! Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            alert.show();
        }

        return filePaths;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `AssetManager` class:
`context.getAssets()` and then use list("") to get a list of the assets in your application.
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)